# Qt Кнопка в верхнем левом углу формы

Tags: qt

В классе наследнике QWidget добавил такое поле:

```
QPushButton *m_sendButton = new QPushButton("Отправить", this);
```

Ни в какой layout эту кнопку я не добавлял! Если вторым паметров передавать this, то она появляется на форме в верхнем левом углу, если нет то нет. Это нормальное поведение и widget'ы автоматом попадают в layout parent'а?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, это [нормальное поведение](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#QWidget). И попадают они не на layout, а на `QWidget` (родителя, тот который `this`).

> If parent is 0, the new widget becomes a window. If parent is another
>   widget, this widget becomes a **child window inside parent**.

Layout сам назначает родителя виджетам, а сам лишь управляет их позиционированием.

> When you use a layout, you do not need to pass a parent when
>   constructing the child widgets. The layout will automatically reparent
>   the widgets (using QWidget::setParent()) so that they are children of
>   the widget on which the layout is installed.

Как грамотно лейаутить написано [здесь](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Пример:

```
QWidget *window = new QWidget;
QPushButton *button1 = new QPushButton("One");
QLineEdit *lineEdit1 = new QLineEdit();
QPushButton *button2 = new QPushButton("Two");
QLineEdit *lineEdit2 = new QLineEdit();
QPushButton *button3 = new QPushButton("Three");
QLineEdit *lineEdit3 = new QLineEdit();

QFormLayout *layout = new QFormLayout;
layout->addRow(button1, lineEdit1);
layout->addRow(button2, lineEdit2);
layout->addRow(button3, lineEdit3);

window->setLayout(layout);
window->show();
```

Comment: Понятно. С не привычки несколько неожиданно...

Answer (score 1):

`QLayout` — это всего лишь вспомогательный класс, задающий положение и размеры ведомых виджетов исходя из геометрии их родителя и соседей.

В случае же добавления виджетов прямым заданием родителя (через `setParent()`), в обход макета, никто их геометрией не управляет и они позиционируются исключительно через ручное изменение их положения (`move()`) и габаритов (`resize()`) силами программы.

Comment: Я полгода занимаюсь разработкой GUI. Всегда получалось так что заводя widget сразу добавлял его в конкретный layout и все было нормально. А тут какая-то фигня. Я просто не заметил объявление этого widgeta в ворохе полей своего класса и появление кнопки которой нет было странно. Спасибо за поддержку!